# Rails - How to put some data inside looping rails

Tags: loops, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to put some data inside my loop.

Example : i have 10 posts. I want to put 1 data for each 3 posts inside those posts.

1. Post 1
2. Post 2
3. Post 3
4. **Data 1**
5. Post 4
6. Post 5
7. Post 6
8. **Data 2**
9. Post 7
10. Post 8
11. Post 9
12. **Data 3**

My codes :

post index:

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

_post.html.erb

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
    <p><%= post.body %></p>
    </div>
```

How to do that? Thanks for helping me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails automatically provides a counter for your collection partial that is named name_of_model_counter (`post_counter`, in your case). So, you could use that to insert data only when the counter is a certain number. i.e add this to the bottom of your partial...

```
...
<% if post_counter % 3 == 0 %>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    # insert data here
  </div>
<% end %>
```

you can use a case statement (or similar) inside the div to determine the exact value of `post_counter` to render different data for each of them.

The important part is that `post_counter` exists and can be used to check which iteration you are on.

**Edit for comment question:**
Assuming you will know how much data there will be ahead of time, you can add another condition like this...

```
# replace x with the iteration number you want to stop at
<% if (post_counter <= x) && (post_counter % 3 == 0) %>
```

Comment: By the way, what is 0 mean in 3 == 0 ?

Comment: `if post_counter % 3 == 0` means "if post_counter is divisible by 3". 0 is the remainder of dividing post_counter by 3, which, when 0, means it is divisible. So, the code will only execute when post_counter is 3,6,9,12,etc...

Comment: Last question sir, what if i want to show the data only on after my 3th post. There is no more data after my 6th post. (stop looping for the data)